# HTML5 picture tag issue related to zoom

Tags: html

How can we use picture tag in HTML5 for zoom images efficiently? While zooming images, images that are given in the media query get displayed instead of the images inside the srcset that given along with the device pixel ratio.

This is one of the sites that I referred: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-responsive-images-with-srcset/

Please find the code below that I used.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 767px)" srcset="../images/kitten-large.png 1x, ../images/kitten-medium.png 2x, ../images/kitten-small.png 3x">
  <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="../images/gallery-img-3.jpg">
  <img src="../images/kitten-large.png" >
</picture>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:** Add Veiwport

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**Step 2: Add Code**

```html
 <style>
    .zoom {
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: green;
      transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: url("your_image.png");
 background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    .zoom:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
    }
    </style>

    <div class="zoom"></div>
```

Hope, It may helps.